# watchdog: Device or resource busy

Tags: c, linux, raspberry-pi, watchdog

I'm trying to feed the watchdog device - `/dev/watchdog` in Raspbian - from C.

The problem is no matter how i try to access the device always throws busy or permission denied errors (as the process is already running and being fed by the system..).

In the [watchdog API](http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/watchdog/watchdog-api.txt) says that *'..the driver will not disable the
watchdog unless a specific magic character 'V' has been sent to
 /dev/watchdog just before closing the file.'* but then again i **cannot** write `/dev/watchdog`.. I tried:

```
echo V > /dev/watchdog //bash, /dev/watchdog: Permission denied

open("/dev/watchdog", O_WRONLY); //C, Device or resource busy
```

Is there any way to free the device so i can control the heartbeat from C?

Comment: What `fuser -v /dev/watchdog` says?

Comment: Nothing, just empty.

Comment: Are you running `echo V > /dev/watchdog` as root? As for the program, are you closing the file after you open it?

Comment: I know it's been a while but never got to solve this and still interested. @CJxD Yes, both echoing and executing the program as root.

Comment: Just to make sure, what are the permissions set on `/dev/watchdog`?

Comment: @CJxD: I have the same issue:  
crw------- 1 root root 10, 130 Mar 17 08:15 /dev/watchdog

Answer (score 6):

I had this problem when i worked with Raspberry Pi. My application used extensive CPU time. After 1 or 2 days work it caused the Raspberry pi hangs. So i decided to use the wtchdog. When i wanted to write watchdog device from C++ program i got same error.

The solution that i found:

open a new rule file
`sudo nano /etc/udev/rules.d/60-watchdog.rules`

and add this line to the file
`KERNEL=="watchdog", MODE="0666"`

After this, i was able to access watchdog form terminal screen or c++ program.

Comment: I cannot try it right now but if it works, this is gold. Thank you very much and I'll keep you updated.

Comment: Didn't work for me: still "Device or resource busy". @TMichel: do you have any progress?

Comment: This is essentially opening up read and write permissions to everybody on the system (which is a bad idea if you care about security). If you're going to do this, do something like `KERNEL=="watchdog", MODE="0660", GROUP="watchdog"` and add your user to the `watchdog` group. Ideally, this should work with root though...

Comment: @CJxD: I understand it changes the file permissions. And it does. But it doesn't help. I've tried the very simple code in 'c' that just opens the file: 
`int fd = open("/dev/watchdog", O_WRONLY);` Run it from root. Got the same error. It looks like the error comes from within the 'open' function.

Answer (score 2):

#### Why the 'device or resource busy' error

The issue I found was that systemd and wd_keepalive seemed to be using the watchdog resource per fuser output:

```
>sudo fuser -v /dev/watchdog
                     USER        PID ACCESS COMMAND
/dev/watchdog:       root      15087 F.... wd_keepalive
```

and

```
>sudo fuser -v /dev/watchdog
                     USER        PID ACCESS COMMAND
/dev/watchdog:       root          1 F.... systemd
```

#### Fix the Busy Error

I removed watchdog timer references from `/etc/systemd/system.conf` to get rid of the busy issue on the `systemd` busy system.

If you're feeling bold, you can kill -9 your wd_keepalive PID, then echo your character toward the `/dev/watchdog` device, if you want to manually control the watchdog.  I prefer just letting the daemon do its thing.

#### Watchdog setup that works on Pi running Stretch 12/17/18

Unlike some other suggestions on SO and the net, I did not need to install watchdog as a device on the Pi e.g. in `/boot/config.txt`. Nor did I need to call any services other than via systemctl.  I just ran

```
sudo apt-get install watchdog
sudo update-rc.d watchdog defaults
```

Then to configure watchdog I put these lines in `/etc/watchdog.conf`

```
watchdog-device = /dev/watchdog

# Set default Timeout
watchdog-timeout         = 14
```

#### Running Watchdog

Then the only thing I needed to do to use watchdog was call this from my application, which I run after bootup:

```
sudo systemctl enable watchdog
sudo systemctl start watchdog
sudo systemctl -l status watchdog
```

Comment: Removing the references to watchdog in `/etc/systemd/system.conf` then rebooting, fixed the problem for me in Ubuntu 16.04.  Thank you.